# Fill by sequence, possibly better std::iota

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++14

**Controversies:** It seems like the algorithm became some sort of `std::transform()`. I started wondering if all mutating algorithms eventually lead to it ...

**Background:** Almost a year ago, I reviewed [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/136052/sequence-generator-with-custom-step-size-start-value-and-operation/136158#136158). The alternative solution was causing pain, because I wasn't sure how to default the function to pre-increment. I really wanted that falling back to iota, and I believe today I realized my dream, although in quite bad way:

**Function objects:**

So it is quite clear that one will need `pre_increment` (it has to be pre, since standard requires it) function object for this.

Here is hilarious amount of boilerplate code:

```
#ifndef AREA51_FUNCTIONS_HPP
#define AREA51_FUNCTIONS_HPP

namespace shino
{
    /**
     * Behaves exactly as pre-increment on `int`s.
     * @tparam T type objects of whose to pre-increment.
     */
    template <typename T = void>
    struct pre_increment
    {
        /**
         * Mutates given value by pre-incrementing and returns.
         * a reference to the same value.
         * @param value value to mutate by pre-incrementing.
         * @return reference to pre-incremented `value`.
         */
        T& operator()(T& value)
        {
            return ++value;
        }
    };

    template <>
    struct pre_increment<void>
    {
        template <typename T>
        T& operator()(T& value)
        {
            return ++value;
        }
    };

    /**
     * Behaves exactly as post-increment on `int`s.
     * @tparam T type objects of whose to post-increment.
     */
    template <typename T = void>
    struct post_increment
    {
        /**
         * Mutates by post-incrementing given value and
         * returns it's previous state. Relies on post-increment
         * of the given `value` itself.
         * @param value value to post-increment.
         * @return `value` before post-incrementing.
         */
        T operator()(T& value)
        {
            return value++;
        }
    };

    template <>
    struct post_increment<void>
    {
        template <typename T>
        T operator()(T& value)
        {
            return value++;
        }
    };

    /**
     * Function object to do inplace multiplication by constant, e.g.
     * on calling `operator()` it will not return value,
     * but rather mutate it. Constant should be supplied during
     * construction. Infers type if `T = void`.
     * @tparam Arithmetic type of the constant to multiply by.
     * The type doesn't need to behave like arithmetic, but it makes
     * most sense that way.
     * @tparam T type objects of whose will be multiplied by a constant.
     */
    template <typename T = void, typename Arithmetic = int>
    class inplace_multiply_by
    {
        const Arithmetic value;
    public:
        /**
         * Initializes constant.
         * @param val value to set the constant to.
         */
        inplace_multiply_by(const Arithmetic& val):
                value(val)
        {}

        /**
         * @param init_value the value to mutate
         * by multiplying by a constant.
         */
        void operator()(T& init_value)
        {
            init_value *= value;
        }
    };

    template <typename Arithmetic>
    class inplace_multiply_by<void, Arithmetic>
    {
        const Arithmetic value;
    public:
        inplace_multiply_by(const Arithmetic& val):
                value(val)
        {}

        template <typename T>
        void operator()(T& init_value)
        {
            init_value *= value;
        }
    };

    /**
     * Function object to do inplace division by constant, e.g.
     * on caling `operator()` it will not return value,
     * but rather mutate it. Constant should be supplied during
     * construction.
     * @tparam Arithmetic type of the constant to divide by.
     * The type doesn't need to behave like arithmetic, but it makes
     * most sense that way.
     * @tparam T
     */
    template <typename T = void, typename Arithmetic = int>
    class inplace_divide_by
    {
        const Arithmetic value;
    public:
        /**
         * Initializes constant.
         * @param val value to set the  constant to.
         */
        inplace_divide_by(const Arithmetic& val):
                value(val)
        {}

        /**
         * @param init_value the value to mutate by
         * dividing by a constant.
         */
        void operator()(T& init_value)
        {
            init_value *= value;
        }
    };

    template <typename Arithmetic>
    class inplace_divide_by<Arithmetic>
    {
        const Arithmetic value;
    public:
        /**
         * Initializes constant.
         * @param val value to set the  constant to.
         */
        inplace_divide_by(const Arithmetic& val):
                value(val)
        {}

        /**
         * @param init_value the value to mutate by
         * dividing by a constant.
         */
         template <typename T>
        void operator()(T& init_value)
        {
            init_value *= value;
        }

    };
}

#endif //AREA51_FUNCTIONS_HPP
```

Nothing really interesting. I decided to leave comments in there since they are part of the code. Feel free to skip over them, they don't carry much of unexpected information.

**Pre-increment and post-increment function objects:**

I always wondered why those are not in the standard library. When writing my own I understood why. I was kind of unsure about semantics, since most (all?) function objects in standard library don't mutate the input, but just return a new value. So I decided to just *do what ints do*, because it is probably least surprising.

**Algorithm:**

```
namespace shino
{
    /**
     * Fills range \f$[first, last)\f$ by repeatedly assigning
     * `initvalue` and mutating it on each element of the range.
     * Does exactly \f$last - first\f$ assignments and mutations.
     * With defaulted `mutator` effectively becomes `std::iota()`.
     * @tparam OutputIterator output iterator type
     * @tparam T value type, assignable to `*first`.
     * @tparam Functor copyable or default constructible
     * type that acts as a functor.
     * @param first iterator to the first element of the range
     * @param last iterator to one past the last element of the range
     * @param initvalue initial value of the sequence
     * @param mutator a functor which mutates `initvalue` to be
     * the next element of the desired sequence.
     */
    template <typename OutputIterator,
              typename T = typename std::iterator_traits<OutputIterator>::value_type,
              typename Functor = shino::pre_increment<>>
    void fill_by_sequence(OutputIterator first, OutputIterator last,
                           T initvalue = {}, Functor mutator = {})
    {
        while (first != last)
        {
            *first++ = initvalue;
            mutator(initvalue);
        }
    }
}
```

I actually struggled with the name really badly. Here are the ones that came to my mind:

- `generate_sequence()` - no. The function doesn't generate a sequence, but rather fill s the given range with the sequence.
- `fill_sequence()` - no. Somewhat confusing and inaccurate.
- `fill_by_sequence()` - this one seems to reflect the behavior much more closely, so I decided to stick with this one.

**Off by one:**

In the beginning I thought that doing this in a loop is wrong, because it will do more than `last - first` mutations and assignments, which is required by the standard. Then I recalled that `last` is actually past the end, e.g. +1, so that prevented me from going to SO and being really ashamed.

**Concerns:**

- General code quality.
- Naming.
- Cutting down amount of boilerplate.
- Consistency and readability of the docs.
- Inplace vs return and assign to itself. I think this is the most toughest design decision of the algorithm.

**Tests:**

```
#include <algorithm.hpp>

#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <array>

void compare_to_iota()
{
    std::array<int, 20> v1 = {};
    shino::fill_by_sequence(v1.begin(), v1.end());

    std::array<int, 20> v2 = {};
    std::iota(v2.begin(), v2.end(), 0);

    bool equal = std::equal(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin());
    if (!equal)
    {
        throw std::logic_error("output of iota and fill_by_sequence don't match");
    }
}

void generate_powers_of_two()
{
    std::array<int, 10> powers_of_two;

    shino::fill_by_sequence(powers_of_two.begin(), powers_of_two.end(),
                            1, shino::inplace_multiply_by<>(2));

    if (powers_of_two[0] != 1)
    {
        throw std::logic_error("fill_by_sequence doesn't correctly set first element");
    }

    for (std::size_t i = 1; i < powers_of_two.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (powers_of_two[i - 1] * 2 != powers_of_two[i])
        {
            throw std::logic_error("fill_by_sequence doesn't correctly mutate the initvalue");
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    compare_to_iota();
    generate_powers_of_two();
    std::cout << "all tests passed";
}
```

Comment: I think it would be possible to convert that `xxx_by` into factory functions, so it would be almost declarative.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, is it any different from [std::generate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Why?

As you already noticed, this is a lot of boilerplate code ... but for what improvement? Further, why do you need a type inferring and a non-inferring version of each of your function objects?

## `std::generate` and lambdas

Do you know [`std::generate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate)? Basically it does what you want: Assign the results of successive function calls (which potentially mutate the function object) to the elements of some range. So, if you want it dead simple, consider this:

```
std::array<int, 10> powers;
// --- generic algorithm follows ---
int n = 1; // might need a better name
// warning: missing test for empty range
*(std::begin(powers)) = n; // or powers[0] if you want it less template friendly
std::generate(std::next(std::begin(powers)), std::end(powers),
              [&n] () { return n *= 2; });
```

This also shows one thing I'd consider an error in your code ...

## off by one

Yes, it will do one superfluous mutation. Consider this example:

```
std::array<int, 1> v1 = {};
shino::fill_by_sequence(v1.begin(), v1.end());
```

How often do you need to mutate the initial value? *Not a single time, of course!* There's only one element which should take the initial value.

Is this a real issue? I think so. Consider this example to generate all powers of two which can be stored in an `int`:

```
std::array<int, std::numeric_limits<int>::digits> powers_of_two;
shino::fill_by_sequence(powers_of_two.begin(), powers_of_two.end(),
                        1, shino::inplace_multiply_by<>(2));
```

**BAAM!** Undefined behavior due to signed integer overflow: After assigning the largest representable power of two, you do another `mutator(initvalue);` which causes said overflow.

## lambdas ...

Perhaps you don't want the "raw, unhidden" lambda there, but instead have names (`inplace_multiply_by`) for everything. Then, instead of writing structure templates ... how about this:

```
template<typename T>
auto inplace_multiply_by(T factor) {
    return [factor] (auto & value) {
        value *= factor; };
}
```

This is not directly applicable to above `std::generate` example, but ...

## Hide the initial value

... works nice with this, which should behave as you wanted (minus the default parameters):

```
template<typename ForwardIterator, typename InitialValue, typename Mutator>
void fill_by_sequence(ForwardIterator from, ForwardIterator to, InitialValue initial, Mutator mutator) {
  if (from == to) { return; }
  *from = initial;
  std::generate(std::next(from), to,
                [&initial, &mutator] () mutable {
                  mutator(initial);
                  return initial; });
}
```

## names

Yes, `fill_by_sequence` is not really a good name, but I cannot come up with anything better atm.

---

## Minor stuff

- `std::cout << "all tests passed";` missing newline here. Otherwise this could screw up some terminals.

Comment: The inferring versions are to force the conversion/cast. Very useful when the input is a proxy or some deceived type. Also, the one more mutation is actually correct, `std::iota` behaves that way too. Thanks for the rest though.